# get div value in a card when click on another part of the card/div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have several cards with the following structure:

```
<div class="uploaded_image">
  <div class="image_actions" data-image-id="1">
    <div class="actions_button rename">Rename</div>
    <div class="actions_button delete">Delete</div>
    <div class="actions_button publish published">Publish</div>
  </div>
  <img src="/image/Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png">
  <div class="image_name">Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png</div>
</div>
```

And then a jquery that goes like this:

```
$(".actions_button.delete").click(function(){
  let image_id = $(this).closest("[data-image-id]").data("image-id");
  let test = $(this).closest("div.image_name").html();
  console.log('data id: ' + image_id);
  console.log('image name: ' +  test);
})
```

what I'm trying to do is when somebody clicks on the delete button, you get in the console the id (that works ok) and the text in the div with the class `image_name`. I'm not sure if it is really early and my brain can't see the error or what but i can't make it work. I've tried other variants but I must be missing something really stupid... help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$(this).closest(".uploaded_image").find("div.image_name")`.

Since `div.image_name` is not a parent of your delete button.

Note you don't have to use `.html()` to get the text of the div, but you can use `.text()`

**DEMO**

```js
$(".actions_button.delete").click(function(){
  let image_id = $(this).closest("[data-image-id]").data("image-id");
  let test = $(this).closest(".uploaded_image").find("div.image_name").text();
  console.log('data id: ' + image_id);
  console.log('image name: ' +  test);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploaded_image">
  <div class="image_actions" data-image-id="1">
    <div class="actions_button rename">Rename</div>
    <div class="actions_button delete">Delete</div>
    <div class="actions_button publish published">Publish</div>
  </div>
  <img src="/image/Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png">
  <div class="image_name">Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, about the `html()` i was getting desperate and thought maybe it was that, but yeah, i use text(), so no worries there. and yes, that was it, i wasn't aiming to the correct one with `closest()`. thanks bro!

Comment: @AleVanHoutte No problem my friend, happy to help

Comment: @AleVanHoutte Btw if your question is solved consider marking any of the solutions that help you as answered so others can see what helped in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `parent()` and `siblings` method to get the `div.image_name`

Since `.closest` method only works in the **same tree** level since the `image_name` is outside the `actions_buttons` - thats why you getting `undefined`.

**Working Demo:**

```js
$(".actions_button.delete").click(function() {
  let image_id = $(this).closest("[data-image-id]").data("image-id");
  let test = $(this).parent().siblings('div.image_name').text()
  console.log('data id: ' + image_id);
  console.log('image name: ' + test);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="uploaded_image">
  <div class="image_actions" data-image-id="1">
    <div class="actions_button rename">Rename</div>
    <div class="actions_button delete">Delete</div>
    <div class="actions_button publish published">Publish</div>
  </div>
  <img src="/image/Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png">
  <div class="image_name">Screen_Shot_2018-03-21_at_10_16_35.png</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AleVanHoutte Happy to help. No problem :)